# Unique "key" prop missing from components with key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following error in console

```
warning.js:33 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `SectionList`. See for more information.
    in div (created by SectionList)
    in SectionList (created by Sections)
    in div (created by Sections)
    in div (created by Sections)
    in Sections (created by SeatingChart)
    in div (created by SeatingChart)
    in div (created by SeatingChart)
    in div (created by SeatingChart)
    in div (created by SeatingChart)
    in SeatingChart (created by Connect(SeatingChart))
```

I have a `SeatingChart` component

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-1 align-top" style={SeatingChartStyle.sectionBuilder}>
            <Sections teamName={this.props.seatingChart.teamName} sections={this.props.seatingChart.sections} saveSection={this.saveSection}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

which renders the `Sections` component

```
renderSectionList(){
  if(this.props.teamName){
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <h3>Sections</h3>
        <SectionList sections={this.props.sections} saveSection={this.props.saveSection} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.renderSectionList()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

which renders the `SectionsList` component

```
previewSection(item, index){
  return (
    <div>
      <SectionItem key={index} section={item} saveSection={this.props.saveSection}/>
    </div>
  );
}

sectionListMap() {
  if(this.props.sections) {
    let sections = Object.values(this.props.sections);
    return (
      sections.map(this.previewSection)
    );
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="col-md-9">
      <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <SectionItem key={-1} section={sectionObj} saveSection={this.props.saveSection} />
        {this.sectionListMap()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Where am I missing my key, each `SectionItem` has a key prop.

Answer (score 1):

```
warning.js:33 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `SectionList`. See for more information.
    in **div** (created by SectionList)
```

You're rendering a list of `div` (containing one `SectionItem` each) and your `div` do not have a key. You can fix the error by moving the `key` prop to your `div` i.e.

```
previewSection(item, index){
  return (
    <div key={index}>
      <SectionItem section={item} saveSection={this.props.saveSection}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this case `SectionItem` doesn't require a key because there's only 1 SectionItem per div as opposed to a list.

Or if you don't need the div, then removing it and keeping the key on `SectionItem` will also fix the error

```
previewSection(item, index){
  return (
      <SectionItem key={index} section={item} saveSection={this.props.saveSection}/>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript: the `Array.map()` function returns an array. In your case: you want to return an array of react components. React wants to see the key at the top level of each component.

Therefore, you need to expose the key at the top level of your `previewSection()` function.

To achieve this: I would remove the superfluous "div" element to render the component as follows:

```
previewSection(item, index){
  return (
    <SectionItem key={index} section={item} saveSection={this.props.saveSection}/>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
previewSection(item, index){
  return (
    <div>
      <SectionItem key={index} section={item} saveSection={this.props.saveSection}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Your keys should not be numeric. So rather than `index`, try something like 
`` {`section${index}`} ``

Even better, the keys should not be based on an order index at all. So if your `sectionObj` has a property like a unique id, that would be ideal to use.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was using [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) in the key prop.

In your case:

```
import uuid from "uuid";

render() {
  return (
    <div className="col-md-9">
      <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <SectionItem key={uuid()} section={sectionObj} saveSection={this.props.saveSection} />
        {this.sectionListMap()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```